# Como dividir corretamente código php em mvc

Tags: php, mvc

Estou fazendo um site para uma disciplina da faculdade e tenho que dividir o código seguindo o padrão MVC. Só que não sei muito bem PHP, estou aprendendo durante a disciplina então queria saber como dividir corretamente o código.

Queria criar uma classe só para conexão com o banco de dados, essa classe ficará no modelo. No controller queria colocar apenas as validações e etc, nada de mexer no db pelo controller. Mas não sei como fazer isso.

Código que eu queria aprender a dividir corretamente:

```
<?php


$email = $_POST['email'];
$entrar = $_POST['entrar'];
$senha = md5($_POST['senha']);
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
$db = mysqli_select_db($connect, 'meudb');
if (isset($entrar)) {        
  $verifica = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT idcliente, nome, email, senha FROM clientes WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha'") or die("erro ao selecionar");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($verifica);
  $nome = $row['nome'];
    if (mysqli_num_rows($verifica)<=0){
      echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Login e/ou senha incorretos');window.location.href='index.html';</script>";
      die();
    }else{
      if (!session_id())
                session_start();
            $_SESSION['logon'] = true;
            $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
            setcookie('usuario',$username,0,"/");
      header("Location:../View/adm.php");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Eu recomendo que você de uma olhada no [framework Slim](https://www.slimframework.com). Com ele você pode criar uma aplicação em MVC, e vai lhe economizar tempo.

Comment: Você pode dar um resumo do que seria MVC pra você? Pergunto pelo fato de ser 'trabalho dado', e as respostas podem não corresponder com a teoria que você aprendeu... `No controller queria colocar apenas as validações`, esse é um exemplo - ha quem trabalhe com validações apenas no Modelo, e quem trabalhe no Controller

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada no framework Slim, porém o prof quer que a gente coloque a mão na massa mesmo.

Comment: Então, eu queria separar tudo mesmo em três pastas. Na model eu queria que tivesse a conexão com o banco, as funções para inserir, remover e editar. No controller a questão do login, a cadastro que ai no caso chamaria a função de inserção definida no model e etc. Coisas assim Papa Charlie, desculpe se não expliquei muito bem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes. Considere a seguinte estrutura de pastas:

```
/projeto (raiz)
    Modelo
        Conexao.php
        Usuario.php
        UsuarioCRUD.php
    Visao
        Login.php
    Controle
        Controle.php
        UsuarioControle.php
```

Você vai dividir o seu codigo entre os arquivos da hierarquia acima. Então fica:

### Modelo

Modelo\Conexao.php

```
<?php
class Conexao{
    private $usuario = 'root';
    private $senha = '';
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $nomeBanco = 'meudb';
    private $conexao = null;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->conexao = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->usuario,$this->senha);
        $db = mysqli_select_db($connect, $this->nomeBanco);
    }
    
    public function getConexao(){
        return $this->conexao;
    }
}
?>
```

Modelo\Usuario.php

```
<?php
    class Usuario{
        private nome = null;
        private $senha = null;
        private $email = null;
                
        public function __construct($nome = null, $senha = null, $email = null){
           $this->nome = nome;
           $this->senha = senha;
           $this->email = email;
        }
        
        public function getNome(){
            return $this->nome;
        }

        public function getSenha(){
            return $this->senha;
        }

        public function getEmail(){
            return $this->email;
        }
    }
?>
```

Modelo\UsuarioCRUD.php

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Usuario.php';

    class UsuarioCRUD{
        private conexao = null;
                           
        public function __construct($conexao = null){
           $this->conexao = conexao;
        }
        
        /*
          @return boolean | Usuario
        */
        public function usuarioExiste(Usuario $usuario){
            $verifica = mysqli_query($this->conexao, 
            "SELECT idcliente, nome, email, senha FROM clientes WHERE    email = '" 
            . $usuario->getEmail() ."' AND senha = '". $usuario->getSenha() . "'") or die("erro ao selecionar");

            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($verifica);
           
            if (mysqli_num_rows($verifica)<=0){
                 return false;
            }
            return new Usuario($row['nome'], $row['senha'], $row['email']);
        }
    }
?>
```

Visao\Login.php

```
<html>
    <head>
    <head>
    <body>
       <form action="/Controle.php" method="post">
           <input name="email" type="text">
           <input name="senha" type="password">
           <input name="entrar" type="submit">
       <form>
    <body>
</html>
```

Controle\Controle.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'UsuarioControle.php';
if(isset($_POST['entrar'])){
    (new UsuarioControle())->logar($_POST);
}else if(isset($_GET['login'])){
    (new UsuarioControle())->login();
}
?>
```

Controle\UsuarioControle.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Modelo' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'UsuarioCRUD.php';
require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Modelo' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Usuario.php';
require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Modelo' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Conexao.php';

class UsuarioControle{
     private $usuarioCRUD = null;
     public function __construct(){
         $usuarioCRUD = new UsuarioCRUD((new Conexao())->getConexao());
     }

     //ao submeter o formulario
     public function _logar($dados){
         $usuario = $usuarioCRUD->usuarioExiste(new Usuario($dados['nome'], $dados['senha'], $dados['email']));

         if($status === false){
             echo 'Usuario inexistente';
         }else{
             if (!session_id())
                
                $_SESSION['logon'] = true;
                $_SESSION['user'] = $usuario->getNome();
                setcookie('usuario',$usuario->getNome(),0,"/");
                header("Location:../View/adm.php");
             }
         }
         die();
     }

     //ao chamar o formulario, algo como http://localhost/?login
     public function login(){
         require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Visao' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Login.php';
     }
}
?>
```

Isso deve ajudar.

Comment: Muito obrigada @Juven_v, era exatamente isso que eu queria entender!!